# Set woocommerce session with array

Tags: php, arrays, session, woocommerce

I was gonna be storing data to woo session.

I was expecting the output to look like this:

```
alemaydz (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [prod_id] => 10035
            [list_cart_type] => 3
            [purchase_mode] => Buy with Credit Card
            [qty] => 4
            [variation_id] => 0
        ),
    [1] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 10036
                [list_cart_type] => 1
                [purchase_mode] => Buy with Credit Card
                [qty] => 1
                [variation_id] => 0
            ),
    [2] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 10037
                [list_cart_type] => 2
                [purchase_mode] => Buy with Credit Card
                [qty] => 1
                [variation_id] => 0
            )
)
```

Below is my current code that doesnt work right now:

```
$cnt=0;
foreach ($cart_contents as $ca) {
        $cnt++;
        WC()->session->set('alemaydz', array(           
            $cnt    =>  array(
                'prod_id'   =>  $ca['product_id'],
                'list_cart_type'    =>  $ca['list-cart-type'],
                'purchase_mode' =>  $ca['purchase-mode'],
                'qty'   =>  $ca['quantity'],
                'variation_id'  =>  $ca['variation_id']                 
            )
        ));
    }
```

Currently the output is just this below, which I dont want just that:

```
Alemaydz (
    [2] => Array
            (
                [prod_id] => 10037
                [list_cart_type] => 2
                [purchase_mode] => Buy with Credit Card
                [qty] => 1
                [variation_id] => 0
            )
)
```

Please can someone help me correct the code above.

Thank you

Comment: Please post the current output of your code, not just the expected output. This will help identify the issue

Comment: Hi @timmah I just edited and put the current output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it myself

```
$cnt=0;
    
    foreach ($cart_contents as $ca) {
        $cnt++;
        WC()->session->set('session-counter', $cnt);    
        $data_arrays[$cnt] = array(
            'prod_id'   =>  $ca['product_id'],
            'list_cart_type'    =>  $ca['list-cart-type'],
            'purchase_mode' =>  $ca['purchase-mode'],
            'qty'   =>  $ca['quantity'],
            'variation_id'  =>  $ca['variation_id']
        );

        WC()->session->set('alemaydz', $data_arrays);
    }
```